# Three comparisons between sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Hello i would like to compare three things of sorting algorithms that include; bubble, insertion, selection sort, quick sort and merge sort but i cant think of any apart from just Time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting Algorithm complexity can be obtained in the number of comparison, the number of swapped elements(meassuring the best, worst and middle case) and memory complexity

Comment: Number comparison and element swapping do they not relate to the same thing as time complexity?

Comment: Nope, for example, in bubble sort, the number of comparison are always n^2 (in the best case, in the worst case and in the middle case) because you always have to compare n-i elements, being i the pass in the second for. But, in bubble sort,in the best case, you don't need to swap any element (for example when your vector is already sorted), in the worst case you need to move n-i elements and in the middle case (n-i)/2. I wish it make it clear :D

Comment: Just a little add, both of them are related with time complexity but this is the way they usually use to measure the time complexity, so you can divide time complexity in these two differents parts.